# Confused about redirecting stdout and stderr from Python script using subprocess

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I have a python script that I'm using to run some bash scripts like so:

```
import subprocess
for x in files:
        print(f"Running process on file {x}")
        subprocess(f"process {x}", shell=True).wait()
```

I run the python script and capture stdout and stderr like so
`python3 script.py &> log`

Strangely though, when I look at the log file, the stdout/stderr from the subprocess comes before the print statement:

```
> cat log
  blah blah from subprocess
  Running process on file x
```

Does anyone know why this is? This only happens when I use the `.wait()` method on the `subprocess.Popen` call.

Comment: outputs on stdout and stderr normally are not synced with each other. Did you try capturing the output into a Python string and displaying it yourself? Also, do you know what the process emits to stdout vs stderr?

Comment: @CadeM : By default, stderr is unbuffered and stdout is buffered. Set stdout to unbuffered, if you need them together.